# key binding in sublime text 2 + SublimeREPL

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimerepl

The default to send current file to SublimeREPL is ctrl+, F, which I want to change to something shorter, say ctrl+. (the period).

I wonder how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Preferences -> Key Bindings-User` and add the following if there are already other custom keybindings there:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+."], "command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "file"}}
```

If the file has no contents yet, just add opening and closing square brackets:

```json
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+."], "command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "file"}}
]
```

Save the file, and double-check `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Transfer to REPL -> File` to see if it now lists the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> shortcut. Obviously, you should also test the key combo itself to make sure it works.

Good luck!

Comment: Matt, what about adding a move to the next line after the key binding? For example, I want `ctrl+l` to be `Eval Line` but then move to the next line afterwards. what would be the syntax for that? Thanks!